# Update the from name in workbench email template

Tags: 8, workbench

I'm trying to update the "from" name in my workbench email template. I created a custom module and added the following hook ('hook_mail_alter') but it's still not updating the from name for my email template. Does the below hook look right?

```
function my_module_mail_alter(&$message) {
  if ($message['id'] == 'needs_review') {
  $message['from'] = 'Full Name <email@address.com>';
  }
 }
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/function/hook_mail_alter/8.7.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that `$message['from']` shall be an email address.

Try to set the `From` header instead, like this:

```
$message['headers']['From'] = 'Full Name <email@address.com>';
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Jdrupal. That worked! However, I had to remove the  if ($message['id'] == 'needs_review') statement for it to work. I was hoping to target a specific email template. Guess I'll need to look into that a bit more.